# cordova console log can not be installed

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to install the cordova console.log plugin.
when i am trying to install it using the command line using:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

I am running it from the path of the root application path
the structure of the folder is:

```
projName
|-- --project
|-- projName
|-- cordova
|-- CordovaLib
|-- projName.xcodeproj
|-- plugin
```

And the error i receive in the command line is

```
[Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.]
```

i should mention that i build the cordova project manually using imports of the frameworks because in the xcode new project window there was not Cordova/Phonegap new project option.

I am using xCode 5.0.1 and cordova 3.1.0

Comment: It sounds you did not create the cordova project with the cordova create command, can you confirm your steps?

Comment: I haven't, i opened a new project directly from xcode and added all the cordova plugins manually, I am getting a good result but no console. is there a way to manipulate it without creating a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is self-explanatory, it is because you have not created a cordova project as it must be created. Keep reading to solve the problem.

## Cordova basic project preparation steps

Based on my comment and your answer, you should follow the cordova workflow for creating projects using the CLI (command line interface), it is strongly recommended to avoid unnecessary problems, and the steps are not hard to follow.

Please follow the steps described here (official doc), read it fully, it will save you more time later if you read it:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

In brief the steps are:

1. Install node.js
2. Install cordova using npm
3. Create a cordova project / app using the CLI
4. Add the desired platform to the project (android, ios, etc, as needed)
5. Work on your project
6. Add cordova plugins as necessary (for example if you need notifications add the notificacion plugin)
7. Build the project
8. Test of device or emulator (in your case iPhone, iPad simulator)

### iOS Platform Guide

Also check the iOS Platform Guide completely, it is very helpful, explain additional instructions to prepare and work with XCode.
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

### Plugins

For each plugin in the API reference you will find instructions to install them using the CLI, as well as to "uninstall" them.
Only install the plugins you will need

Just for reference, the code to install notifications-dialogs plugin using the terminal (run the command inside your project folder):

```
 $ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

On the other hand, the easier way to solve the problem is create the new project following the noted steps and later just add your existing code or files to the proper folders, as well as add the required plugins, not that difficult.